# Finding the amount of different elements at array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashtable, big-o

We have an array at size `n`.  How we can find how many different types of elements we have at `n` and what is the amount of each one?

For example: at `{1,-5,2,-5,2,7,-5,-5}` we have 4 different types, and the array of the amounts will be: `{1,2,1,4}`.

So my questions are:

1. How we can find how many different elements there is at the array?
2. How we can count the amount if each one?

Now, I try to solve it at Omega(n), I try a lot but I didn't find a way. I try to solve it with hash-tables.

Comment: I don't get it why `{1,2,1,5}` is the array of amounts.

Comment: What does "different type" mean in the context of this question?

Comment: The straight forward solution with a hash table is O(n). What did you do to get a worse complexity?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - "different type" = different number

Comment: And so why is 1 listed twice? And where did the 4 come from?

Comment: what is the min/max value of elements in the table ? Also how did you try to solve it ? What was your approach ?

Comment: its simple use `std::map` with `key` as different values and `value` as there count

Comment: @Shan That will work, but it takes time O(n log n). I think the OP is looking for an O(n)-time solution.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - `1` is twice for the 1 and for the 7.....

Comment: So the "array of amounts" is actually pretty useless alone since it doesn't tell you which numbers occur once, twice, once, and five times?

Comment: @Shan, thank you! but I need algorithm...

Comment: Loop through the array, for each value, look it up in a map/dictionary. If it doesn't exists, add it with a value of 1. If it already exists, increase its value. At the end, every key has a value indicating how many times that key occurred.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I don't need this information :-)

Comment: OK, sorry, but perhaps you haven't figured this out by now, but *this question is far from clear*. You need an algorithm, I gave you an algorithm. **What do you need then?** Stop saying what you *don't* want, describe *what you do want!*

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, OK, I'm sorry, I'll try to be clear..  First of all - what is "look it up in a **map/dictionary**"?? Thank you!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but it will be O(n^2)? no?

Comment: A dictionary/map data structure has amortized O(1) access.

Comment: I need to find algorithm with hash tables that will give me how many times each element is appear.... @LasseV.Karlsen What is the best way? I try to understand your solution but I didn't understand it...

Comment: @tchrikch - I tried to make hash table with the a prime with the prime that is highest  from the max value... but then it's it's O(`max[n]`).... So I'm afraid it's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get frequency of an element in an array.

- Initialize a Hash where every new key is initialized with value 0.
- Loop through array and add this key to hash and increment the value.

In JavaScript:

```
hash = {};
a = [1,-5,2,-5,2,7,-5,-5];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if(hash[a[i]] === undefined)
        hash[a[i]] = 0
    hash[a[i]] = hash[a[i]] + 1;
}

console.log(hash.toSource());
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the meaning of: `hash[a[i]] === undefined`?

Comment: And you will get somewhere: `hash[-5]` it's legal??

Comment: I try to run your solution but It doesn't compile! :-(

Comment: What do you mean `it doesn't compile!`? Since you didn't specify any language, I just demonstrated an algorithm in `JavaScript` language. Many people have given you algorithms and some even posted some demo code in other languages. If you are expecting copy-paste kinda code, you are looking in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax and specific data structures you use will vary between languages, but the basic idea would be to store a running count of the number of instances of each value in an associative data structure (HashMap, Dictionary, whatever your language calls it).

Here is an example that will work in Java (I took a guess at the language you were using). 
It's probably bad Java, but it illustrates the idea.

```
    int[] myArray = {1,-5,2,-5,2,7,-5,-5};
    HashMap<Object,Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Object,Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) 
    {
        if (occurrences.get(myArray[i]) == null)
        {
            occurrences.put(myArray[i],1);
        }
        else
        {
            occurrences.put(myArray[i],occurrences.get(myArray[i])+1);
        }
    }
```

You can then use your HashMap to look up the distinct elements of the array like this
occurrences.keySet()

Other languages have their own HashSet implementations (Dictionaries in .NET and Python, Hashes in Ruby).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't a code... I need algorithm..:-)

Comment: An algorithm is an abstract procedure that you follow to get a specific result. A program is an implementation of an algorithm. You can't really describe an algorithm without putting it into some language either a programming language or a human langauge.

Comment: I will leave it as an exercise for you to turn the Java/C++ code we gave you into an abstract description of the algorithm. It's incredibly important that you be able to recognize the same algorithm whether it's in Java, C++, English, or Swahili.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to solve this problem.The question that asked here might be asked in different ways.Here the the simple way to do it with `std::map` which is available in STL libraries.But remember **it will be always sort by key**.

```
int arr[]={1,-5,2,-5,2,7,-5,-5};
int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
map<int,int>v;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(v[arr[i]])
        v[arr[i]]++;
    else
        v[arr[i]]=1;
}
map<int,int>::iterator it;
for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();++it)
cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
return 0;
```

it will show output like

```
-5 4
1 1
2 2
7 1
```

Comment: Your solution is great, but I need the **algorithm** The map class doesn't help me...:-(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about 'Count Sort'

Although i am not sure i understood correctly what you actually want to ask. Anyway, i think you want to:

1.) Scan an array and come up with the frequency of each unique element in that array.

2.) Total amount of unique elements

3.) all that in linear computational time

I think, what you need is Counting Sort. [See algo on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm).
You can obviously skip the sorting part. But you must see how it does the sorting (the useful part for your problem). It, first, calculates a histogram (array of size nominally equal to the number of unique elements in you original array) of frequency of each key. This works for integers only (although you can always sort other types by putting integer pointers).
So, every index of this histogram array will correspond to an element in your original array, and the value at this index will correspond to the frequency of this element in the original array.

For Example;

your array x = {3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3}

//after calculation, you will get

your histogram array h[0 to 4] = {1, 2, 0, 4, 1}

i hope that is what you asked

Comment: I'll will use it!! but at this time I don't know how this help me... can you explain more please?

Comment: Yes, you right!! But there is one thing that is missing - How can I know that size of the new array? And how can know if we have a value one them more time?

Comment: @SumIL the length of the histogram array (h.length; / h.getSize;) is the number of unique elements.
And for more than a single occurrence of an element 'x' you look at the value stored in h[x];